# Unable to start automatic download

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have created an iframe with some javascript to start download on page load after 5 seconds but it is not working for me nothing is happening and file is not downloading

```
<meta name="content-disposition" content="attachment; filename=http://dannykg.com/freebooks/4MindBlowing-Tips.pdf;">

<iframe id="download" width="1" height="1" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

```js
function startDownload () {         
    document.getElementById("download").src="http://dannykg.com/freebooks/4MindBlowing-Tips.pdf"; 
} 
setTimeout (startDownload, 5000);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force pdf file download window from iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23727030/force-pdf-file-download-window-from-iframe)

Comment: I am unable to understnd his code can you post in it to my answer to explain better as I am unable to ask question there

Comment: Do you use any server-side language(PHP, ASP.net, JSP...)?

Comment: javasript only it's html page

Comment: thankyou.html only the above code is there on the page and a h1 heading

Comment: Do you have to use the Iframe to download or is it ok if you have to use an other method?

Comment: I would prefer with iframe as would be easy way isnt it or is there anything else

Comment: Check the console output of your browser when you open this html file. Press F12 and go to CONSOLE. Ist here the error message "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf"? This would mean, that your server transfers the file differently.

Comment: Check this answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23013574

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because almost every browser today has got a built in PDF viewer, which means that your browser tries to display the PDF inside the invisible Iframe.

One way preventing this would be telling your server to use another content type for the PDF.

But there is a easier way, you just have to compress your PDF into a zip file. Then browsers will download it.

Comment: So how about if it opens in a new tab ??

Comment: I don't think it will open in a new tab if you use the Iframe method

Comment: so what other method you could suggest can you please help me with that  it could download or open in new tab

Comment: with href and placing download like this <a href="http://dannykg.com/freebooks/4MindBlowing-Tips.pdf" download>click here.</a> but auto load not working :(

Comment: You have to create a zip file of the PDF and use it instead